# Minimum number of observation when performing Random Forest

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, sample-size

Is it possible to apply RandomForests to very small datasets?
I have a dataset with many variables but only 25 observation each. Random forests produce reasonable results with low OOB errors (10-25%).
Is there any rule of thumb regarding the minimum number of observations to use?
In fact one of the response variable is unbalanced, and if I'm going to subsample it I will end up with an even smaller number of observations.
Thanks in advance

Comment: How many features does the training set contain?

Comment: It contains 33 predictors and 4 response variables (I should perform 4 RFs)

Comment: check [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/10079/rules-of-thumb-for-minimum-sample-size-for-multiple-regression) out for heuristics.

Comment: I should also add that in my case, 25 observation covers 83% of the population. I'm in fact running the analysis on a small taxonomic family (30 sp) where each species is an observation. Would it be better if I'd just reduce the number of predictors? I can avoid using some of them.

Comment: 83% coverage should give you confidence. Also your OOB error is lowish so you have some proof that things are working.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Absolutely RF can be used on these type of datasets (i.e. p>n).  In fact they use RF in fields like genomics where the number of fields >= 20000 and there are only a very small number of rows - say 10-12.  The entire problem is figuring out which of the 20k variables would make up a parsimonious marker (i.e. feature selection is the entire problem).

I don't have any ROTs about minimum size other than if your model doesn't work well on a held back sample (or Hold-One-Back cross validation might work well in your case) well then you should try something else.

Hope this helps